# More than one input is Const Op

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow

I am trying to serve the following gitrepo in opencv: https://github.com/una-dinosauria/3d-pose-baseline and the checkpoint data can be found at the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWzojlLp259MF9qSFpiVjl0cU0/view

I have already constructed a frozen graph which I can serve in python and was generated using the following script:

```
meta_path = 'checkpoint-4874200.meta' # Your .meta file
output_node_names = ['linear_model/add_1']    # Output nodes
export_dir=os.path.join('export_dir')
graph=tf.Graph()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
# Restore the graph
    loader=tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
    loader.restore(sess,'checkpoint-4874200')

    builder=tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                     [tf.saved_model.SERVING],
                                     strip_default_attrs=True)


# Freeze the graph
frozen_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess,
    sess.graph_def,
    output_node_names)

# Save the frozen graph
with open('C:\\Users\\FrozenGraph.pb', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Then I optimized the graph by running:

```
optimized_graph_def=optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
    frozen_graph_def,
    ['inputs/enc_in'],
    ['linear_model/add_1'],
    tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)
g=tf.gfile.FastGFile('optimized_inference_graph.pb','wb')
g.write(optimized_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

and the optimized frozen graph can be found at: https://github.com/alecda573/frozen_graph/blob/master/optimized_inference_graph.pb

When I try to run in opencv the following I get this runtime error:

```
OpenCV(4.3.0) Error: Unspecified error (More than one input is Const op) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200310::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::getConstBlob, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp, line 570
```

Steps to reproduce

To reproduce problem you just need to download the frozen graph from the above link or create yourself from the checkpoint data and then call the following in opencv with the below headers:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
 #include "opencv2/dnn.hpp"


string pbFilePath = "C:/Users/optimized_inferene_graph.pb";
//Create 3d-pose-baseline model
cv::dnn::Net inputNet;
inputNet = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(pbFilePath);
```

Would love to know if anyone has any thoughts on how to address this error.

You can see the frozen graph and optimize graph I generated with tensorboard from the attached photos.

[image: frozen_graph]
[image: optimized]

I have a feeling the error is arising from the training flag inputs but I am not certain, and I do not want to go trying to edit the graph if that is not the problem.

I am attaching the function in opencv that is causing the issue:

```
const tensorflow::TensorProto& TFImporter::getConstBlob(const tensorflow::NodeDef &layer, std::map<String, int> const_layers,
                                              int input_blob_index, int* actual_inp_blob_idx) {
    if (input_blob_index == -1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < layer.input_size(); i++) {
            Pin input = parsePin(layer.input(i));
            if (const_layers.find(input.name) != const_layers.end()) {
                if (input_blob_index != -1)
                    CV_Error(Error::StsError, "More than one input is Const op");

                input_blob_index = i;
            }
        }
    }

    if (input_blob_index == -1)
        CV_Error(Error::StsError, "Const input blob for weights not found");

    Pin kernel_inp = parsePin(layer.input(input_blob_index));
    if (const_layers.find(kernel_inp.name) == const_layers.end())
        CV_Error(Error::StsError, "Input [" + layer.input(input_blob_index) +
                                  "] for node [" + layer.name() + "] not found");
    if (kernel_inp.blobIndex != 0)
        CV_Error(Error::StsError, "Unsupported kernel input");

    if(actual_inp_blob_idx) {
        *actual_inp_blob_idx = input_blob_index;
    }

    int nodeIdx = const_layers.at(kernel_inp.name);
    if (nodeIdx < netBin.node_size() && netBin.node(nodeIdx).name() == kernel_inp.name)
    {
        return netBin.node(nodeIdx).attr().at("value").tensor();
    }
    else
    {
        CV_Assert_N(nodeIdx < netTxt.node_size(),
                    netTxt.node(nodeIdx).name() == kernel_inp.name);
        return netTxt.node(nodeIdx).attr().at("value").tensor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the error originates in `getConstBlob` (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp#L570). `getConstBlob`is called several times in `populateNet` (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp#L706), which is called in all overloaded definitions of `readNetFromTensor` (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp#L2278). Those may be starting points for where to place breakpoints if you want to step through with a debugger.

The other thing I noticed is that the definition of `populateNet` which I believe you're using (supplying a `std::string`: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gad820b280978d06773234ba6841e77e8d) requires two arguments - both the model path (`model`) and a `configuration (`config`), which is optional and defaults to an empty string. In the unit tests, it looks like there are both cases - with and without configuration provided (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/test/test_tf_importer.cpp). I'm not sure if that would have an impact.

Lastly, in the script you provided to replicate the results, I believe the model file name is misspelled - it says `optimized_inferene_graph.pb`, but the file you point to in the github repo is spelled optimized_**inference**_graph.pb.

Just a few suggestions, I hope this may help!